# How to pass Gatling session attributes in an exec() invoking another library (generated gRPC code)?

Tags: gatling

Newbie Gatling+Scala question: I’m using [George Leung](https://github.com/phiSgr)'s gatling-grpc library (which is modeled after the http library) and trying to pass a value from the  session (generated in a feeder), into a non-DSL, non-Gatling method call, specifically calls populating the gRPC payload object.

---

Before I start, let me add that it seems I can’t use the sessionFunction (`Expression[T]`) form of `exec`, which would resolve my issue:

```
.exec{ session => { … grpc(…).rpc(…)… }}
```

…because, AFAICT, the `grpc` call must be the last thing in the block, or else it’s never evaluated ... yet it **can’t** be the last thing in the block because there’s no way to coerce it to return a Session object (again, AFAICT).

---

Therefore, I have to use the `ActionBuilder` form of `exec` (`grpc(...)` returns a `Call` so this is as designed):

```
.exec( grpc(…).rpc(…)... )
```

and this works… until I have a gRPC *payload* (i.e., non-Gatling) method call to which I need to pass a non-constant value (from a feeder).

In this context, I have no access to a `Session` object, and the Gatling Expression Language is not applied because the library defining the gRPC types I need to use (to generate the payload) has no knowledge of Gatling.

So, in this fragment:

```
  .header(transactionIdHeader)("${tid}.SAVE") 
  .payload(Student.newBuilder()
    .setId(GlobalId.newBuilder().setValue("${authid}_${uniqId}").build()).build())
  )
```

…the first call evaluates `${tid}` because the param in the second parens is `Expression[T]`, and hence is evaluated as Expression Language, but the second call fails to evaluate `${authid}` or `${uniqId}` because the external, generated library that defines the gRPC type GlobalId has no knowledge of Gatling.

So...

1. Is there a way to invoke the EL outside of Gatling's DSL?
2. Or a way to access a `Session` object via an `ActionBuilder`?

   - (I see that the Gatling code magically finds a Session object when I use the sessionFunction form, but I can't see whence it comes — even looking at the bytecode is not illuminating)
3. Or, turning back to the `Expression[T]` form of `exec`, is there a way to have an `ActionBuilder` return a `Session` object?
4. Or, still in the `Expression[T]` form, I could trivially pass back the existing `Session` object, if I had a way to ensure the `grpc()...` expression was evaluated (*i.e.,* imperative programming).

---

Gatling 3.3.1, Scala 2.12.10

The gatling-grpc library is at [phiSgr/gatling-grpc](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc); I'm using version 0.7.0 (`com.github.phisgr:gatling-grpc`).

(The gRPC Java code is generated from .proto files, of course.)

Comment: After further inspection, I'm beginning to suspect that the problem is that I'm using code generated (by `protoc`) for Java, but the gatling-grpc library, somewhat reasonably, appears to assume (in some cases) that the code was generated for scala.  IOW: *D'oh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [Gatling-JavaPB](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/tree/master/java-pb) integration.

To see that in action, see [here](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/blob/master/bench/src/main/scala/com/github/phisgr/gatling/pb/bench/TestUpdateExpr.scala).

---

The `.payload` method takes an `Expression[T]`, which is [an alias](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/2ec47d804966330595179ef9ee6425fcb3cd4579/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/session/package.scala#L27) for `Session => Validation[T]`. In plain English, that is a function that constructs the payload from the session with a possibility of failure.

Much of your frustration is not knowing how to get hold of a `Session`. I hope this clears up the confusion.

---

In the worst case one can [write a lambda to create an expression](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/blob/67450356715f100a43048af2b2cb5ac50d065faa/bench/src/main/scala/com/github/phisgr/gatling/pb/bench/TestUpdateExpr.scala#L78). But for string interpolation or accessing one single object, Gatling provides [an implicit conversation](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/2ec47d804966330595179ef9ee6425fcb3cd4579/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/ValidationImplicits.scala#L63) to turn an EL `String` into an `Expression`.

The problem is you want to construct well-typed payloads and Gatling's EL cannot help with that. The builders’ setters want a `T`, but you only have an `Expression[T]` (either from EL or the [`$` function](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/blob/67450356715f100a43048af2b2cb5ac50d065faa/src/main/scala/com/github/phisgr/gatling/grpc/GrpcDsl.scala#L45)). The library mentioned above is created to handle that plumbing.

---

After importing `com.github.phisgr.gatling.javapb._`, you should write the following.

```scala
...
.payload(
  Student.getDefaultInstance
    .update(_.getIdBuilder.setValue)("${authid}_${uniqId}")
)
```

---

For the sake of completeness, see the [warning in Gatling's documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/) for why defining actions in `.exec(sessionFunction)` is not going to work.

Comment: the `$("sessionAttrName")` syntax worked just fine with your gatling-javapb -- _thanks!_